# English and Chinese Version of a Website

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way (possibly using JavaScript) to change the language of a website from English to Chinese (for an example) using a link?

Comment: Are you trying to translate your page?  Or load text that you have already translated?  Any reason why you wouldn't want to simply link to the Chinese version?

Comment: Brad is right, we need a little more information about what is happening on the site.

Comment: I'd like to load text that has already been translated. I'd prefer it if I could just use one website.

Comment: embed a google translator on your site...z

Answer (score 0):

In case you're searching for an easy way to offer your site in various languages, I believe your best bet will be Google's [Website Translator](https://translate.google.com/manager/website/).

Take into account, however, that the translations will be just about as reliable as the regular Google Translate results, which -- as you might know -- still leave a bit to wish for. For more rigorous stuff, you will need to create a more technical solution.

**Edit:** Noticed your comment reply above. It really depends a lot on how your site is constructed. If it's dynamically generated with content stored in a database, you could have one column for each one of your translations; the code generating your page must then be informed about which version to use, which could be done in several ways: I'd personally advise to structure your solution with this 'argument' in the URL, something along the lines of your-site.com/lang/page-slug-here, but you could also set a session variable ('just clicking a link'), or go by the user's browser language settings as default, and so forth.